# Windows equivalent of Linux fifo

Tags: c++, windows, ipc, named-pipes, fifo

I use a function from a library that take a file name as parameter. In my application I receive the data from the network, so I can't feed the library with the downloaded data directly because I can't write it on the disk. To solve the problem I'm using Linux fifo (created with `mkfifo()`) and I give the fifo name to the library.

Now I have to port the code to Windows and I'm looking for an equivalent of Linux fifo mechanism. I already tried [Windows Named Pipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/named-pipes) but these pipes can't be opened like regular files with standard library functions like `fopen()` (unless I'm missing something).

Do you know a Windows mechanism to read data from memory as a file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Named pipes are in fact what you want. If you want to use them with the C runtime, `fread`, `fwrite` and `fclose` use the `_popen` or `_wpopen` function to create the pipe. On Windows, pipes are part of a separate namespace from file names. There is simply nothing you can pass to `fopen` that is equivalent.

Comment: CreateFile (which is the API fopen depends on) can open the client end of an existing named pipe but not create the pipe itself.